# An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Tags: c#, xaml

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AdView1.LoadNewAd();
            IMAdView AdView = new IMAdView
            {
                AdSize = IMAdView.INMOBI_AD_UNIT_320X50,
                AppId = "My app id", 
                Name = "AdView1"
            };
            try
            {
                IMAdRequest adRequest = new IMAdRequest();
                AdView.IMAdRequest = adRequest;
                ContentPanel.Children.Add(AdView);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            { }


            AdView1.RefreshInterval = 40;
            AdView1.RefreshInterval = IMAdView.REFRESH_INTERVAL_OFF;
}
```

Here i want to integrate an Inmobi ad in my Windows Phone 8 Application.but i get the 'System.Net.WebException'. can anyone Suggest what should i do to Remove this type of Error.

Comment: An obvious problem is that your AppId is fake.  Common problems are forgetting to ask for the capabilities in the manifest.  The error you get is caused by the library violating the contract of a WinRT component.  That's a bug, little you can do about it of course.  If you can't sort it out then you need to ask the vendor for help.

Comment: Was there an inner exception? If so, the inner exception may be a more helpful diagnostic.